# How to find out the total memory bytes used in java with the objects that has been removed out by GC?

Tags: java

I want to find the total memory allocation until now with the objects that has been removed out by GC?

Is there any way to find out the above with the help of any **library** or Classes like **Runtime**, **ManagementFactory** and **MemoryMxBean**?

Comment: imo, what you're really looking for is a profiler / java-agent, which would let you see this information.

Comment: I dint get to what you've said. Could you please elaborate on how to find out the above programatically?

Comment: The profiler wouldn't be a programmatic approach necessarily, but you could utilize the java-agent available from some profilers (e.g. YourKit or VisualVM) to access the API they use, retrieving that information yourself programmatically. There's a little research involved in learning that, of course.

Answer (score 0):

long memavailable = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory(); // quantity of clear memory

There are a couple of other views of memory by methods in class Runtime